# How to Scrape PressReader Website for News with Horizontal Scrolling Pagination

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape news articles from the PressReader website. Each page on the site only displays a few news articles, and to see more articles, I need to scroll horizontally (left or right) instead of vertically. The new content loaded after scrolling replaces the previous content. How can I retrieve all the content at once without losing the previously loaded articles?

I am using Python and Selenium for web scraping. I've tried scrolling into view and scrolling actions, but they don't seem to work as expected for horizontal scrolling. The website uses JavaScript to load more content.

Is there a way to scrape all the news articles that are loaded through horizontal scrolling? If so, how can I achieve this using Python and Selenium? Are there any specific techniques or methods I can use to ensure that I capture all the content without losing the previously loaded articles?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

https://www.pressreader.com/search?query=Evergrande&in=ALL&date=Anytime&hideSimilar=0&type=2&state=2

js = "var q=document.documentElement.scrollWidth=10000000"
driver.execute_script(js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Scrape PressReader Website for News with Horizontal Scrolling Pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76969056/how-to-scrape-pressreader-website-for-news-with-horizontal-scrolling-pagination)

Comment: No. This is another post that I thought I had deleted. 
driver.execute_script("var q=document.documentElement.scrollWidth=10000000") or driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "toolbar-slider-right")) are not working.
Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use site scroll bar to scroll left.

Even if native js behaviour worked as expected in your case, new articles are loaded async and trigger is navigation right button.

In any case to get new articles you should click on it.

Steps that should be performed:

1. Wait for visibility of `#scroller` to ensure the site is loaded
2. Wait for presence of nav buttons `.readingnav.rn-right`
3. Getting last button from array and perform move to it via `ActionChains`
4. Click on it
5. Get list of articles
6. Wait for last article element to stop moving
7. Repeat

```py
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

def scroll_articles():
    next_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.readingnav.rn-right')))[-1]
    actionChains.move_to_element(next_button).perform()
    next_button.click()
    last_article = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'article')[-1]
    wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(last_article)

url = "https://www.pressreader.com/search?query=Evergrande&in=ALL&date=Anytime&hideSimilar=0&type=2&state=2"
driver.get(url)
next_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#scroller')))
while True:
    scroll_articles()
```

You should replace `while True` to condition that you need to stop scroll. I placed it just for example.

Also, be aware that getting list of articles usually easier from official site API or from network, Selenium is not the best tool for this purpose.

Comment: ```
executable_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe'
url_login = "http://ezproxy.lb.polyu.edu.hk/login?url=https://www.pressreader.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option(), executable_path=executable_path)
driver.get(url_login)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
enter_search_page(wait)

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
scroll_bar = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='scroller']")))
while scroll_bar:
    scroll_articles(wait, scroll_bar, actionChains)
```

Comment: I tried to solve this problem but failed. It shows that **selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds**.
What should I do ？ Here is the Github link: https://github.com/Chen-Sue/PressReader